# How to create an UniqueConstraint for M2M relationship table in Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, orm

```py
class MyChoices(models.IntegerChoices):
    CHOICE_A = 1
    CHOICE_B = 2


class MyModelA(models.Model):
    choice = models.IntegerField(choices=MyChoices.choices)
    payload = models.CharField(...)


class MyModelB(models.Model):
    models_a = models.ManyToManyRelationshipField(MyModelA, ...)
    payload = models.CharField(...)
```

Is there a way I can create a `UniqueConstraint` on `app_my_model_b_my_model_a` table with `MyModelA.choice` field and `MyModelB` primary key field?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a model as [**`through=…`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through):

```
class MyChoices(models.IntegerChoices):
    CHOICE_A = 1
    CHOICE_B = 2


class MyModelA(models.Model):
    choice = models.IntegerField(choices=MyChoices.choices)


class MyModelB(models.Model):
    models_a = models.ManyToManyRelationshipField(MyModelA, through='MyModelC')

class MyModelC(models.Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(MyModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model_b = models.ForeignKey(MyModelB, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['model_a', 'model_b'], name='unique_a_b')
        ]
```

Comment: I've mistyped what I meant, sorry, I need to make a `UniqueConstraint` for one model field and other model id.

Comment: @khjfpggkfmkqqucifw: no that is not possible, you normally should model that differently, for example encode the `payload` in the m2m model.